# How exactly does a basic open set in uniform topology look like?

Tags: general-topology

[How to prove that the uniform topology is different from both the product and the box topology?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/297085/how-to-prove-that-the-uniform-topology-is-different-from-both-the-product-and-th)

Here in the link I don't see how V is an uniform-1/2 ball centred at 0.

Comment: What is the difficulty? $|x_n|<\frac{1}{2}$ for all $n$ is the same as $d(x,0)<\frac{1}{2}$ surely?

Comment: There is one difficulty as we are dealing with infinite products. while trying to prove the two sets (B(0,1/2) and the infinite product) equal, at one point the "supremum" thing turns the strict inequality to less than equal.So they are not equal. Ofcourse one is contained in the other.

Comment: @almagest It *is* true that $\sup x_n \lt a \implies x_n \lt a \; \forall n$, but it results in a weaker statement as the converse is not necessarily true: we actually have $x_n \lt a \; \forall n \implies \sup x_n \leq a$. Consider the set $\left\{\frac{n}{n+1} ,n \in \mathbb{N} \right\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The original (and, unfortunately, accepted) answer was incorrect. This is a corrected version.**

The set in question is

$$V=\left\{x\in\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}:d(x,\mathbf{0})<\frac12\right\}\,,$$

where

$$d:\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}\times\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}\to\Bbb R:\langle x,y\rangle\mapsto\sup_{n\in\Bbb N}\min\{1,|x_n-y_n|\}\,.$$

Since $d$ is the uniform metric on $\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$, $V$ is **by definition** the open ball of radius $\frac12$ centred at $\mathbf{0}$ with respect to the uniform metric on $\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$, just as

$$\left\{x\in\Bbb R:|x|<\frac12\right\}$$

is the open ball of radius $\frac12$ centred at $0$ with respect to the usual metric on $\Bbb R$.

If one unpacks the definition, one can see that

$$\begin{align*}
V&=\left\{x\in\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}:\sup_{n\in\Bbb N}|x_n|<\frac12\right\}\\
&=\left\{x\in\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}:\exists r\in\left(0,\frac12\right)(|x_n|<r\text{ for all }n\in\Bbb N)\right\}\,.
\end{align*}$$

Note that this is not the same as

$$W=\left\{x\in\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}:|x_n|<\frac12\text{ for all }n\in\Bbb N)\right\}\,:$$

the point $x=\left\langle\frac12-\frac1{2^{n+1}}:n\in\Bbb N\right\rangle$ is in $W$ but not in $V$, since

$$\sup_{n\in\Bbb N}\left(\frac12-\frac1{2^{n+1}}\right)=\frac12\,.$$

Comment: @Fahim: You’re welcome!

Comment: Your counterexample is wrong. The supremum of that sequence is $\frac{1}{2}$, so actually $x \notin V$.